Unable to produce the messages for other clients
I've written below code to make a chat server in rust that accepts multiple clients. I'm at a stage where (code available here) it's able to accept multiple clients and writes the message of one client to all other clients. I tried to make a struct to hold user data, it's stored in a vector and wrapped in an Arc-Mutex.
The problem I'm running into now is messages from one user are not showing up in other ones (The code reaches the part that writes to the socket, I used print statements to verify as much, but nothing appears on the other end). However, when I close a client connection, if there's another client connected it will send all the messages to that one (for example, connect client 1, send a couple messages, connect client 2. now whatever I do on client 2 does not show up on the server, no debugging statements are triggered. any messages i send on client 1 are the same as earlier. now if I disconnect client 1, any messages sent after connecting client 2 are sent to client 2. the same follows for any number of connections). I'm assuming it's an issue with how I'm storing the connected clients data, but I'm way too early into learning and don't know enough to reliably figure anything out
use tokio::{io::{AsyncBufReadExt, AsyncWriteExt, BufReader}, net::TcpListener};
use tokio::sync::{broadcast, Mutex as TokioMutex};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};



// Define a struct to store user information including their username
#[derive(Debug)]
struct UserInfo {
    username: String,
    addr: std::net::SocketAddr,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let listener: TcpListener = TcpListener::bind("localhost:8080").await.unwrap();

    let (tx, _rx) = broadcast::channel(10);

    // let users = Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![]));
    let users = Arc::new(TokioMutex::new(vec![]));

    loop {
        let (mut socket, addr) = listener.accept().await.unwrap();
        println!("New connection from: {}", addr);

        let tx = tx.clone();
        let users = users.clone();
        let mut rx = tx.subscribe();

        tokio::spawn(async move{
            // Ask for username
            let username = ask_for_username(&mut socket).await.unwrap();
            println!("User {} connected from: {}", username, addr);

            // Store user information
            let user_info = UserInfo {
                username: username.clone(),
                addr,
            };

            // Add user to the list of users
            let mut users_guard = users.lock().await;
            users_guard.push(user_info);

            let (read_half, mut write_half) = socket.split();

            let mut reader = BufReader::new(read_half);
            let mut line = String::new();

            loop {
                tokio::select! {
                    result = reader.read_line(&mut line) => {
                        if result.unwrap() == 0 {
                            break;
                        }
                        println!("Broadcasting message from {}: {}", username, line);
                        tx.send((line.clone(), addr)).unwrap();

                        line.clear();
                    },
                    result = rx.recv() => {
                        let (msg, other_addr ) = result.unwrap();

                        println!("Received message from another connection: {:?}", msg);


                        write_half.write_all(msg.as_bytes()).await.unwrap();

                        println!("Message sent to the user");
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }

}

async fn ask_for_username(socket: &mut tokio::net::TcpStream) -> Result<String, std::io::Error> {
    let mut username = String::new();

    // Send a message asking for username
    socket.write_all(b"Please enter your username: ").await?;

    // Read the username from the client
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(socket);
    reader.read_line(&mut username).await?;

    Ok(username.trim().to_string())
}

If one looks in the repo, the main branch contains the standard chat server implementation and the usernames branch is tracking attempts for implementing usernames. As mentioned earlier I haven't had any success with it. I've tried using the tokio and std mutexes, but both produce the same sort of errors.

Your problem is here:
// Add user to the list of users
let mut users_guard = users.lock().await;
users_guard.push(user_info);

users_guard stays in scope until the end of the enclosing block, and so the lock is held until then.  Consequently only one client can be in the read loop at any given time; the others remain suspended awaiting the lock until that client disconnects, whereupon the mutex is unlocked and another client can make progress.
You should explicitly drop(users_guard);, place the above code into its own block or else change the above to users.lock().await.push(user_info); in order to ensure that the lock is not held any longer than necessary.
